# PostgreSQL user only drop some tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, permissions

Is there a way to have a PostgreSQL user that can drop all but specified tables?

We need the user to be able to drop some tables but not all. It would be preferred to be able to use something like [revoke](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-revoke.html) where we could specify which tables the user should not be able to drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're running 9.3, you could potentially use an [event trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html) to catch the tag `DROP TABLE` and prevent that for certain users.

Denish Patel has a example in his blog post here [Preventing Human Errors in Postgres](http://www.pateldenish.com/2014/02/preventing-human-errors-in-postgres.html). Search for the string "Function to prevent single table drop". That should give you enough of a start to modify for your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

`DROP TABLE` isn't a `GRANT`able right, it's held only by the table owner and the superuser.

Kassandry has already noted that event triggers are one option.

Another is to create a wrapper function, like `my_drop_table(thetable regclass)`, and mark it `SECURITY DEFINER` as the owner of all the tables (or superuser, but I really don't recommend that). The function would check if the table is one of the protected ones and, if not, issue the `DROP TABLE` command via `EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I;', thetable)`.